# Use Maven and Docker + Nexus 3 behind NGinx with HTTPS

Tags: maven, ssl, nginx, docker, sonatype

I generated certificates for my docker client and deamon following Docker recommendations: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/#create-a-ca-server-and-client-keys-with-openssl

But... I'm using Sonatype Nexus 3 as my private docker registry.

And I have a frontal NGinX.

I would like to setup NGinx with a self-signed certificate to be able to use Nexus as a registry.

Basically, I have that setup for NGinx:

```
    ssl_certificate                 /home/AAA/certificates/adgroupe.priv/server-cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key             /home/AAA/certificates/adgroupe.priv/server-key.pem;
    ssl_protocols                   SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers                     RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers       on;
```

The 2 certificates being the ones generated with Docker documentation (link above).

I then can add with keytool my server.cert to my keystore, but how can I make both Maven and Docker trust that certificate? I mean, no one trust my CA since I generated it myself...

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a Debian based operating system, And i did it that way.
On your client AND your server, you just have to take the  cert file and add it to the ca-certificates.

```
root@test:~/certs mkdir /usr/share/ca-certificates/myRegistry.example.com
root@test:~/certs cp certificate.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/myRegistry.example.com/
root@test:~/certs echo "myRegistry.example.com/certificate.crt" >> /etc/ca-certificates.conf
root@test:~/certs update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 1 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....done.
# restart docker to refresh trusted CA
root@test:~/certs systemctl restart docker
```

You will only be able to acces with the Common Name you gave it (for me it's ): myRegistry.example.com.
Because I specified it when i created the cert

```
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:myRegistry.example.com
```

hope this helps